# Google Analytics only showing active MOBILE users?

Tags: google-analytics

When I go to my site on mobile it almost instantly shows up as an active user on google analytics. But when I do so on PC it never shows up as an active user. Even tried going to the site through Rabb.it

Also it shows active users 1 but "no data has been received the last 48 hours", does it just take time to update?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related and may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the JS debugger on your PC browser?  Maybe there is an error that is causing the script to load incorrectly?

I've seen Firefox block the actual HTTP request to the analytics tracker, for example if you have private browsing turned on.  I would start with using either Chrome's Developer tools or Firefox in conjunction with Firebug to try to take a peek under the covers as to what is occurring, i.e.

1. Verify that the JS actually loads correctly
2. Check for debug errors on the JS console
3. Check to see if the HTTP request is actually going through.

If your browser is blocking it you will see something like the image below.

[image]

Comment: It shows you. Still doesn't show me. Trying to check what you told me..

Comment: Using the developer tools I don't see anything. No warnings or errors or things like that. I just made the google analytics to test it out and havent filtered my own IP yet. It's strange that it worked when you visited the page but not when I visited through rabb.it

Comment: Yes, it looks like its working from here.  Have you cleared you cache completely?  Are you sure you are fetching the page from that actual server and not looking at a cached copy?

Comment: Do you see the HTTP request for Google Analytics at all? Maybe there is a security device in-line that is manipulating or restricting your traffic?  Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: I tried Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge. I do show up on Microsoft Edge but not on the others. On Firefox Firebug the console is empty, the debugger shows the analytics.js source and the network tab only shows the css file.